# Can we have infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In  Wikipedia's Hilbert space [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Separable_spaces) on separability, it says:

> A Hilbert space is separable if and only if it admits a countable orthonormal basis. All infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces are therefore isometrically isomorphic to $ℓ^2$.

I guess *orthonomal basis*  means Hamel basis, since Schauder basis are always countable by definition. But according to this [theorem](http://planetmath.org/banachspacesofinfinitedimensiondonothaveacountablehamelbasis), any Banach space of infinite dimenesion will have uncountable Hamel basis only.

So why does it mention infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces? Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: No, orthonormal basis means Hilbert basis (which is, in the countable case, also a Schauder basis). A complete normed space cannot have a countable Hamel basis (by Baire's theorem).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, I'll try to understand the difference between Hilbert and Schauder basis. Btw, you say "complete normed space cannot have a countable Hamel basis", that's for the infinite dimensional case, right?

Comment: In that, "countable" means "countably infinite". Yes, finite-dimensional spaces are complete.

Answer (score 2):

$\ell^2$ itself is a simple example of an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space.

The orthonormal basis is just a maximal orthonormal set -- so a Hamel basis of a dense subspace which is, in addition, orthonormal. It can certainly be countable.